# Calculating homography of multiple markers on a single plane

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, homography

I've got an algorithm that calculates the homography of a number of  markers in a single image, using OpenCV's `findHomography`. This works fine, but due to the size of the markers/resolution of the images, the rotation calculated is often quite inaccurate (mainly around the x and z axes of the marker, assuming y is up). I'd love to find a way to improve this.

I have a hypothesis that the fact that I know all the markers are on the same plane (they're on a table) should help improve the homography - I then just need to work out the rotation of the marker around a single axis - but I don't know enough to put this in to practice. Can anyone give me any guidance on this?

This is an example of the situation I'm trying to deal with (the images on the markers are different in reality).

[image]

Comment: you must know the relative position between markers (or even the absolute position on the plane if you need the plane coordinates later). BUT in your example you could compute homogr from a single arrow (if it ptovides >= 4 points/markers) and after that compute the relative position of any other marker with that homogr

Comment: you could try to compute 3 single homographies from 3 single markers (in your example) and try some kind of averaging or choose the "best" one.

Comment: That's my current approach, but often I find that one of the markers has a very different orientation while the other two are fine. If I had a large number of makers, I could discard outliers in some way, but with 2 or 3 markers, that's a trickier thing to do.

Comment: my idea would be: 1. each marker has 4 or more known points. 2. when you have the homography you can find the plane position of the other markers by only homography and pixel location of the other markers' points. 3. if the homography is good, a "reconstructed" complex marker must have correct shape in reconstructed plane positions. If the homography is bad, the reconstructed marker will have a wrong shape. If it's not possible to understand what I mean (not easy in a comment), I'll try to create an answer with some graphics :)

Comment: @Micka: I get what you mean - that's an interesting approach. I guess if you find a homography that produces a valid shape (which I guess you can fairly quickly tell using various metrics e.g. the ratio of width/height) then you can transform your points using that homography then calculate an affine transformation and combine the two together to produce a homography for the marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the idea of getting higher precision for the estimated homography by using multiple marker images spread across the scene.

This approach can be realized using Nonlinear Optimization. But it’s a little tricky.

### Assumptions, Model, Data

Let’s take your example of 3 printed marker images placed across a table and assume all your assumptions hold.

And now let’s assume that for each of the 3 printed marker images you’ve found `N` **point correspondences**.

Point correspondences here means that for a printed marker image you can associate `N` image **pixel positions** with corresponding `N` **real world positions** `(x,y)` in centimeters (or some other unit) with respect to a known real world "printed marker coordinate system" (for example, with coordinate `(0,0)` located at the center of a marker image).

The problem is that the "printed marker coordinate system" is only known locally for each printed marker image. What we need is to bring those coordinate systems together and find a way to express "printed marker coordinate system" positions in a single, global coordinate system. So we need to figure out a relation between them.

### Relation between each marker’s homographies

We want to compute a homography which uses all the correspondence data from different printed marker images. Therefore, it is important to understand how they relate to each. Specifically, we want to find a common coordinate system for all marker images in order to formulate an optimization problem.

Now, based on the point correspondences, and using conventional methods, compute 3 homographies:

- `H1` maps "printed marker coordinate system" positions of marker image #1 to image pixel coordinates
- `H2` maps "printed marker coordinate system" positions of marker image #2 to image pixel coordinates
- `H3` maps "printed marker coordinate system" positions of marker image #3 to image pixel coordinates

Let’s assume shortly that no measurement and computation errors are present (just hypothetically). Then, the homographies differ only in a rotation [image] and translation [image] of the respective "printed marker coordinate systems".

Then, the following equations hold:

[image]

[image]

with the rotation and translation defined as follows:

[image]

### Putting everything together

That means that H1 equals H2 "up to" a rotation [image] and translation [image] and H1 equals H3 "up to" a rotation [image] and translation [image].

This gives us a way for transforming positions of marker image #2 into the coordinate system of marker image #1 (case for positions of marker image #3 can be handled analogous):

[image]

Now, in a real world scenario, these equations will hold only approximately. But nevertheless they give a motivation for estimating the rotation and translation between any pair of printed marker images:

[image]

[image]

Now, using [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2), we can find estimates of six auxiliary variables [image] which describe how the printed marker images #2 and #3 are located relative to #1.

That’s all we need for preparation to have start values and a model to formulate a nonlinear optimization problem.

### Nonlinear optimization problem

The final goal is to find 8 coefficients of a homography matrix `H` which uses all point correspondences from all printed marker images at the same time:

[image]

Using the above model, we can define a system of nonlinear equations. It will have `8 + 6` unknowns:

- 8 homography coefficients
- 6 auxiliary variables [image] which describe how the correspondences from marker image #2 and #3 will be mapped to the marker image #1 coordinate system

Using the `N` point correspondences of 3 marker images, we get `N*3*2 = N*6` equations. That means, we need `N>=3` point correspondences in order to have more equations than unknowns. Interestingly, the minimum `N=3` correspondences per marker image in case of the multiple marker image scenario is less than the minimum `N=4` in the case of a single marker image scenario.

I’ll not add the formulation of the nonlinear optimization problem in more detail at this point as the general idea of how to approach the problem was already explained.

For solving the nonlinear optimization problem, [Newton’s method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) can be used, for example.

### Remark

All matrices in the above equations need to be normalized like follows:

[image]

Comment: Martin, thank you for your detailed answer. I can't say I fully understand it right now, but I'm going to give it a detailed read (and re-read)!

Answer (score 1):

The homography model *assumes* that your markers are on a plane. This is not additional information that you can add. If your markers were *not* and a plane the function would not work at all.

If your markers are all in the *image* plane, i.e. all images are top-view images, then you can use an affine model (or lower) instead of the homography. It is not clear from your question if this is the case.

If all your markers are always on the same plane, you can calculate the plane homography from all of them *simultaneously*. The result should be more numerically stable the more points you have and the more they span the image. It should be more accurate than calculating each marker's homography independently.

The question is what your corresponding points are - you would need to know the relative position of the markers in the image as well.
If you use the same reference marker image the calculation will most likely fail.

Comment: I'm aware that to compute the homography, all the points you provide need to be on the same plane. I'm talking about calculating the homography of _multiple_ markers that lie on the same plane (each marker being made up of a number of planar identifying points). 

I've added an (mocked up) image to the original question that might help clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. The problem with calculating the homography of the plane the makers is on is that I don't know the relative position/orientation of the markers (as that's what I'm trying to work out in the first place!)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that in order to employ standard homography estimation approaches based on point correspondences the user has to know the relative positions of the markers in the world. However, there is a way to improve the homography estimation process. In [this](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/21/17/5752) paper called **Homography Ranking Based on Multiple Groups of Point Correspondences**, there is a method that can systematically recommend which homography could potentially yield the best results in the very same setting as described above.

Moreover, the authors also documented an attempt to formulate the task as a non-linear optimization problem. In the supplementary section, there is a discussion related to this issue. Long story short, it shows that it is very hard to achieve usable results. I am mentioning this because one of the previous answers suggested it.

*Disclaimer: I am the lead author of the aforementioned paper. I came up with the solution when facing the very same problem in a real-world application during my Ph.D. research.*