# How to find homography

Tags: computer-vision, transform, transformation, homography

I need to find homography matrix, which transforms 2d image coordinates into real world coordinates(2D). What I have is an image of a wall and three non overlapping triangles on the wall. `The length of each side of the triangle is 1 meter` (on the wall), also I know the all the corner postions of the triangles in the image. How can I calculate the `homography` matrix using these triangle information ?

[image: Example Image]

If I assume bottom left corner of the triangle as (0,0) on the wall then I can find other 2 coordinates of the triangle based on that (3 known coordinates), how can I use information from the other triangles to find the homography matrix.

Comment: I guess you mean the (2D) coordinates on the wall, isn't it? And you want to map pixel coordinates of your image to these 2D "wall" coordinates. Am I right? 3D isn't possible if I understand you correctly.

Comment: yes, on to the 2d coordinates of the wall...

Answer (score 3):

Image coordinates cannot be transformed to real world  coordinates with mere Homography matrix alone.When you transform image point to real world coordinate you get

[image]

Here [image] are image coordinates, [image] are 3D points in real world frame. From image coordinates alone we don't know scale factor [image] . So when we multiply inverse of Homography matrix:

[image]

***X',Y',Z'*** are not equal to ***X,Y,Z*** .

---

One approach to solve for ***X',Y',Z'*** is instead of finding Homography, you can use opencv's [solvepnp()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#bool%20solvePnP(InputArray%20objectPoints,%20InputArray%20imagePoints,%20InputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputArray%20distCoeffs,%20OutputArray%20rvec,%20OutputArray%20tvec,%20bool%20useExtrinsicGuess,%20int%20flags)) function. You have 3D coordinates of corners of triangles known in 3D space, and corresponding pixel coordinates. With camera's intrinsic parameters (***K***) you can find Rotation and translation of camera from Real world's origin. Having known camera intrisics you can compute ***X',Y',Z'*** as

[image]

---

Another approach is, you at least 3 3D points and corresponding image coordinates. You can solve for H using linear equations solver

Answer (score 0):

So, I assume that you want to map your 2D pixel coordinates to 2D coordinates on your wall. All you need are the point correspondences (at least four). So let's say you know some point coordinates on your wall and you know at which pixel coordinates these points appear on your image.

All you have to do is passing these points to a ready made solution e.g. [findHomography](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography) provided by [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) or [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30809-ransac-algorithm-with-example-of-finding-homography/content/findHomography.m) you'll find something for Matlab.

Both return a homography (3x3 matrix). You can use it to transform further coordinates. OpenCV does this for you with [perspectivetransform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#perspectivetransform) (is actually a simple matrix multiplication with [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates), so it's not a big deal in Matlab as well).

Comment: I have triangles on the wall, If assume bottom left corner the triangle as (0,0) on the wall then I can find 2 other coordinates of the triangle based on the current origin. Using this I can find only 3 coordinate positions on the wall. How can I use information from other 2 triangles. ?

Comment: @gfkri but findHomography in OpenCv doesn't expect world coordinates isn't it

Comment: It expects a vector with two dimensional coordinates, why should there be a difference in passing pixel coordinates and passing e.g. centimeter? @user61455 Oh, you don't know the position of the triangles relatively to each other?! Hmm let me think some time about it. I am not sure if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31424844/1617744) has been asked before.

You can solve for the homography using point correspondences from multiple triangles by defining auxiliary variables which explain how the triangles (in real world "wall coordinates") are rotated and translated relative to each other. And then solve for the homography coefficients and auxiliary variables at the same time by using a nonlinear optimization formulation.

In your case, you have `N=3` point correspondences per triangle. I have provided a solution for this problem which will work if you have at least `3` triangles.

In addition, you’ll need to use [Equilateral triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle), but you stated that you already do.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39693477/1617744) for details.